# Is there a TFS guide for editing workflow?

Tags: tfs

We've recently starting using TFS. Currently just for source control.

We're considering using work items instead of our current bug tracking system. I've heard that the work flow is customizable and would like to have a go at it.

A small example is that sometimes while working a bug, someone may decide that the product documentation needs updating, maybe to explain a workaround or if the bug fix caused a change to a screen layout, new screenshots would be required in the help file. I'd like it to work so that if somebody ticks a 'required docs' check-box on the work-item, after the bug is fixed and tested, the work-item would be automatically assigned to our documentation team.

I've heard TFS does support work-flow, but am struggling to find a suitable guide on how I'd go about customizing it.

Can you point me in the right direction? Or, have I misunderstood what's possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Welcome to the patterns & practices Team Development with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server project site! This guide shows you how to make the most of Team Foundation Server. It starts with the end in mind, but shows you how to incrementally adopt TFS for your organization. It's a collaborative effort between patterns & practices, Team System team members, and industry experts.

http://www.codeplex.com/TFSGuide